# Laravel 5.8 insertar un nuevo registro de usuario a una tabla existente

Tags: php, sql, laravel

En mi proyecto laravel funciona correctamente el login pro defecto que aparece al agregar en consola

```
>php artisan make:auth
```

mi tabla es la que tiene por defecto el proyecto nuevo de laravel 5.8 al usar

```
>php artisan migrate
```

decidi agregar un campo directamente en mi tabla xampp-> phpmyadmin despues de la columna name , la columna apellidoPaterno con un valor "AP"

al tratar de combrobar que todo funciona bien trate de registrar un nuevo usuario pero me sale error

Donde ejecuta la funcion/querry para insertar estos datos en una tabla SQL?

Comment: y especificaste la nueva columna en el model?

Comment: no estoy seguro donde esta el modelo que crea automaticamente para modificarlo :(

Comment: si agregas el error que te aparece sería mas fácil para la comunidad ayudarte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel tiene herramientas que facilitan el manejo de tablas de datos, su creación y modificación de manera rapida y automatica. Incluso con proyectos que ya están en uso y que no pueden por ningún motivo perder datos.

En todos mis proyectos siempre he tenido que hacer cambios en la estructura del modelo USER, casi siempre adicionando nuevas columnas, tales como 'lastname' y 'role_id'.

Supongamos que queremos adicionar dos columnas 'Lastname' y 'role_id' porque queremos dar diferentes roles a nuestros usuarios. Hay CUATRO pasos:

**1. Modifica Base de datos**

Agregar una nueva “migration” asi:

```
php artisan make:migration add_new_columns_to_users
```

Esta acción creará una nueva migration en el directorio *'databases/migration’*  con el nombre: *fecha_actual_add_new_columns_to_users.php*

Edita la nueva “migration” como sigue:

```
public function up() { 
        Schema::table('users', function($table) { 
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index(); 
    }); 
}

public function down() { 
        Schema::table('users', function($table) { 
    $table->dropColumn(lastname);
        $table->dropColumn('role_id');
    }); 
}
```

Por ultimo usa el comando "*migrate*" para modificar la base de datos:

```
php artisan migrate
```

**2 Actualiza el modelo USER. (user.php)**

```
…
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname','lastname', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'
];
…
```

**3. Actualiza el controlador de registro de usuario (app/http/controllers/auth/RegisterController.php):**

El metodo de validacion:

```
...  
protected function validator(array $data)
   {
       return Validator::make($data, [
           'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
           'lastname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
           'role_id' => ['required', 'integer'],
           'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
           'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
       ]);
   }
...
```

y el metodo de creación:

```
...
   protected function create(array $data)
   {
       return User::create([
           'name'      => $data['name'],
           'email'     => $data['email'],
           'password'  => Hash::make($data['password']),
           'role_id'   => 3,
           'lastname'  => $data['lastname'],
       ]);
   }
...
```

**4 Actualizar los campos en el formulario de creación de usuarios.**

Debes adicionar el campo "input" en el archivo HTML "resources/views/auth/register.blade.php" para aceptar el apellido (lastname).
Por supuesto, en el caso del ‘role_id’ de este ejemplo, seria un campo oculto en el formulario. Pero eso ya es HTML común y corriente.

Finalmente, en mi experiencia personal, debes siempre usar idioma ingles en el código (lastname). Nadie sabe quien va a leer tu código en el futuro.

Espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 1):

Amigo si vas a hacer el uso de Eloquent deberías de crear una nueva migración de la tabla o modelo que quieras modificar con el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:migration [coloca un nombre que identifiques] --table=[nombre de la tabla a modificar]

php artisan migrate
```

También si quieres hacer tus propias tablas sin hacer el uso de Eloquent podrías hacer procedimientos de almacenados en el gestor de base de datos de tu gusto y en laravel hacer la llamada respectiva con

```
Call nombre_del_prodecimiento
```

Comment: hola, la verdad soy muy nuevo en laravel usual mente uso codeigniter, mientras desarrollo un nuevo proyecto tiendo a hacer muchos cambios a las tablas al prinsipio y laravel me lo a complicado mucho. al momento quiero agregar a usuarios niveles , valores como apellido paaterno y materno entre otros. hay una forma mas directa ? o podrias explicar como funciona call nombre_del_prodecimiento? gracias igual mente me fue util tu respuesta

Comment: Si quieres hacer tu mismo el manejo de tus tablas como te indicaba al menos yo hago el uso de procedimientos de almacenados para poder realizar un INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE desde el frontend (Laravel), ya la manera como desarrolles tus procedure eso es por tu parte, ahora en el controlador "Usuario" supongamos que así lo llames en tu proyecto como por ejemplo mas o menos deberías llamarlo así si haces el Query directamente en el Controller. **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;** eso para hacer el uso y esto **$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);** para algun Query

Comment: No es tan extenso lo que te puedo explicar, pero si deseas agregarme a cualquiera de las redes sociales, para poder ayudarte con ese tema rápido para que lo entiendas, adicional a eso cubrir algunas otras dudas que tengas.

Answer (score 1):

Comprueba en la Base de Datos que el nuevo campo que has creado permite valores nulos o tiene un valor predeterminado.

En el modelo en app\User.php en:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email'
    ];
```

Aquí debes agregar el nuevo campo que has creado, si haces asignación de datos en masa.